# Select data attribute from row only for rows with checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table has 2 columns: checkbox and name.

```
<table id="data">
    <tr class="header">
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" class="download" />
        </th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="1">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="download" />
        </td>
        <td>One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="2">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="download" />
        </td>
        <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="3">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="download" />
        </td>
        <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to select data attribute from those rows that have checkbox selected. Right now I'm doing it this way:

```
$(document).on('click', "#select", function (e) {
    var mydata=[];
    $.each($('#data tbody tr:not(.header)'), function(i, row) {
        if($(row).find('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked"))
            mydata.push($(row).data('id'));
        });

    console.log(mydata);
});
```

This works fine, but can this be done better/faster?
Here is my working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/yytR2/2/

Also how can I uncheck checkbox in header when one of more checkboxes in body are unchecked and check it when all will get checked?

**EDIT:** My final working code (thanks to @tymeJV):

```
$(document).on('change', "#data tr.header input.download", function (e) {
    $('#data tbody tr:not(.header) input.download').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});

$(document).on('change', "#data tr:not(.header) input.download", function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") && $('#data tr:not(.header) input.download:not(:checked)').length == 0) {
        $('#data tbody tr.header input.download').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#data tbody tr.header input.download').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$(document).on('click', "#select", function (e) {
    var rows = $("#data tr:not(.header) td input:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
    }).get();
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
var rows = $("#data tr:not(.header) td input:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
}).get();
```

It iterates yet, but only checked rows.

Comment: This looks fasted :) What about second part? How to uncheck checkbox in header if I uncheck at least one in body?

Comment: Bit more code @Misiu -- Attach a `change` to your checkboxes, each time it's checked, you have to set the status of the top level checkbox.

Comment: Got this for now: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/yytR2/4/ but I need to check if all checkboxes in body are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $(".download:checkbox").map(function() {
    return $(this).parents('tr').data('id');
 }).get()
```